# How to stack notifications in android using phonegap and urban airship

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, urbanairship.com

I have an application built with phonegap/cordova and it is using Urban Airship for push notifications. The notifications are sent in batches, upwards of 10 at a time. Currently, for every notification a device receives it adds an item to the notification status bar and the notification drawer. Is there a way I can stack these notifications without writing native java code? I can't find anything in cordova's or Urban Airship's documentation allowing this.